# Converting some C# code to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm working on converting some C# code to Javascript.  I have the following code snippet.

```
float goldenRatioConjugate = 0.618033988749895f;
float currentHue = (float) random.NextDouble();

currentHue += goldenRatioConjugate;
currentHue %= 1.0f;
```

My question is I don't understand what the last line is doing?  I've never seen a modulo operation with a float.

Comment: That's a strange piece of code. It's converting a random `float` between `0` and `1` to another random `float` between `0` and `1`. You might as well remove the last 2 lines as they are effectively a noop.

Comment: I would say that this question is more about what `%= 1f` does specifically rather than how mod generally works with floats.

Answer (score 5):

It will set `currentHue` to the fractional portion of `currentHue`

For example:

- 1.5 will become 0.5
- 3.488 will become 0.488

Answer (score 1):

Let suppose

```
currentHue = 2.5f;
currentHue = (currentHue % 1.0f); /* Output will be 0.5*/
```

It will first calculate modulus and then assign it to the `currentHue` which is `0.5` in the above case

```
currentHue %= 1.0f;
```

you can write above line as below

```
currentHue = (currentHue  % 1.0f);
```